# Adapter Security in MFP 8 with Default Scope

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Am using MFP 8, created an adapter with a new procedure and in configuration, i can see the new procedure is having DEFAULT_SCOPE, when i try to get response from that adapter, am getting INVALID_REQUEST error.

If i add secured="false" for that procedure, it works fine.

I need to keep the default scope security. How to get response from client side ?

Comment: Did you ObtainAccessToken before Calling the resource request ?

Comment: if it is DEFAULT_SCOPE, the scope is registeredClient only right ?

Comment: if you simply get ObtainAccessToken() without any scope it will obtain token for scope RegisteredClient. After that if you call resourceRequest it would work.

Comment: Thanks.. is there any possibility that this call works only after SUCCESSFUL DEVICE REGISTER ?

Comment: App registration will trigger on first time Call from App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this Tutorial https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/

Like I said you need to ObtainAccessTOken() with empty scope before calling the protected adapter calls with "DEFAULT_SCOPE"

Comment: thanks for the help. Is there anyway where i can pass the LOGINID as USERID while registering for PUSH notification ? now, my Device is getting registered by USERID is empty.

Comment: For user Id, you need to enable UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck

Comment: thanks, my Device Register is throwing INVALID_REQUEST on HTTPS but it's working on HTTP. 

1. Adapter Function with DEFAULT_SCOPE
2. Calling ADAPTER from APP, Gives proper RESPONSE on HTTP but not in HTTPS. 

Any help ?

Comment: Can you pass the network trace / wireshark ? when it is https is it passing through some other intermediary ?

Comment: Also is there any additional error noted in Server out log when this happens?

Comment: I have added the latest iFix and TLS in config, its worked fine.